Emission Shader Issue in Blender 4.1: Strength Above 1 or 2 Turns White
Whenever I'm using the emission shader in Blender 4.1 and increase the strength above 1 or 2, it turns white. I understand that putting high strength values should automatically dilute the selected color to white, but in my case, the values are just too low. This means I cannot have an object emitting enough desired light. For example, I was working on a sun and was hoping to have an orange with at least a 50 strength value for a nice emission, but I can't go beyond 3 without it turning white. The results are just a solid color. A couple of days ago, it was working perfectly, and I only discovered this issue today.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Have you changed Color Management?
AgX and Filmic color management provides better color handling in over-exposed and oversaturated areas. For example:



Default
AgX









You can change it in Color Management tab:

